# Deleting an item from an array. (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working in Java right now, and I'm attempting to make an array copy itself into a temporary array, and then overwriting again with a new list, however the code isn't functioning.

MobilePhoneInventory.java

```
public void delete(MobilePhone p) {
    MobilePhone[] temp = new MobilePhone[list.length-1];
    int adj = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (p != list[i]) {
            temp[i-adj] = list[i];
        }
        else adj = 1;
    }
    list = temp;
    numMobilePhone--;
}
```

MobilePhoneStart.java

```
    if (e.getSource() == myDelete) {
        if (inven.size() > 1) {
            inven.delete(inven.get(see));
            see--;
            if (see < 0) {
                see = 0;
            }
            showMP();
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

For some reason it's not creating the new list. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would use ArrayList or have a look at how it does it.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use arraylist in this.

Comment: Why would you not use array.clone to get the new array?

Comment: I need to remove an object from the array.

Comment: @user3033222 and you are not allowed to read the code from ArrayList or learn anything from it?

Comment: Where in the second code block are you testing `list`?  The call to `showMP()`?

Comment: The showMP() is calling the previous object in the list on an append().

Comment: How about array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, element)?

Comment: Does `inven.get(see)` return the object at index `see` or does it return a copy? If it returns a copy, then the `!=` in the `delete()` method loop is always going to be `true`.

Comment: I thought that fixed the problem, but It's still happening.

Answer (score 3):

When copying Java arrays, my preferred way is with `System.arrayCopy`. In your case, you have a test inside the loop which actually probably makes your approach more suitable.

Without seeing the rest of your class and how its mutable state works, it's hard to be sure about the solution. Overall, it looks OK. Possibly, there is a mistake with a reference somewhere so you don't get the thing you thought you'd got.

But one thing worth testing is that your equality test is the correct one:

```
if (p != list[i]) {
```

because you may find a `! ... .equals` test works more reliably than `!=`.

Comment: I have the same result as the way I had it before. It doesn't remove the object from the array.

Comment: I like this answer.  You should prefer `equals()` over `==`.  The former is testing equality as you define it in the class definition, while the latter is testing whether you are looking at the exact same instance, which may not be what you mean here.  The default `equals()` implementation just calls `equals()` on each field in an object - you may want to do more (or less).  If you do write your own implementation of `equals()` on `MobilePhone`, make sure you read this link: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Comment: This ins't the answer. It's a good practice but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: How do you identify a `MobilePhone`?  Is it with some kind of `id` field and nothing more?  If so, you should write your own `equals()` method for `MobilePhone` that just compares `id`.  Otherwise the default `equals()` methods may be comparing fields you do not care about in two `MobilePhone` instances with the same `id`, and returning `false` for equality.

Comment: "For some reason it's not creating the new list" - it clearly is, but maybe it gets lost due to overwriting the wrong field or being overwritten by a subsequent alteration. Could you check how the rest of the class works, because the bug may not be in the code you listed.